How to solve React native expo App header or Android phone header color background issue
Why my react native expo cli app showing like this (Pic 1) when I install apk file from expo.dev.
But when I use expo eas dev-client(expo go) then the app work perfectly(Pic 2).At the time of developing the app is working fine.


Please see the both images for better understanding.

This question is similar to: React Native with Expo Status Bar showing white on Android and content pushed down. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you, sir, My problem solved by using the below code in App.json file-
"androidStatusBar": {
"backgroundColor": "#FF5733 ",
"barStyle": "dark-content",
"translucent": true,
"hidden": false

},
